# Polymorphic records not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations

I have these three models that are polymorphic:

`Banner.rb`

```
class Banner < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :pictures, as: :imageable, dependent: :delete_all
    belongs_to :user
    ...
end
```

`Product.rb`

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :pictures, as: :imageable, dependent: :delete_all
    ...
end
```

`Picture.rb`

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
    ...
end
```

I am facing issues when *updating* a record for both `banners` and `products`. I am able to create a record (e.g. a banner) that has multiple pictures fine. But when I try to update that record with new pictures, the record updates but the pictures don't get saved to the database.

Below is my `_form.html.erb` for the banner model:

```
<%= simple_form_for @banner, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
  <%= f.submit "Add Banner" %>
<% end %>
```

Below is the relevant parts of my `banners_controller.rb`:

```
class BannersController < ApplicationController

    before_action :find_banner, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def new
        @banner = current_user.banners.build
    end

    def create
        @banner = current_user.banners.build(banners_params)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @banner.save
                if params[:images]
                    params[:images].each do |image|
                        @banner.pictures.create(image: image, imageable_id: @banner.id)
                    end
                end

                format.html { redirect_to @banner, notice: 'Banner was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render json: @banner, status: :created, location: @banner }
            else
                format.html { render action: "new" }
                format.json { render json: @banner.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @banner.update(banners_params)
            redirect_to root_path 
        else
            render "edit"
        end
    end

    private

    def banners_params
        params.require(:banner).permit(:name, :pictures)
    end

    def find_banner
        @banner = Banner.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

I'm not sure why the images aren't getting properly updated. When the update method is called, it succeeds and I get redirected to the `root_path`, but when checking in the DB, the pictures have not been updated.

Below is an example of the params being passed when updating:

```
{
"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bnTdEljiWFsIPAV92lQvNidrcIhxwh+IP2OdELYey1UEwzFQUeQchSXa10sCtjvgRRupyqhWKmHBI7SpTVDpmQ==", 
"banner"=>{"name"=>"new banner 3"}, 
"images"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f85acb99e00 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/7r/ypx2k4pd5jxgyy7kt6wzmv_r0000gn/T/RackMultipart20170819-46445-17e2f5i.png>, @original_filename="C#.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images[]\"; filename=\"C#.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f85acb99db0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/7r/ypx2k4pd5jxgyy7kt6wzmv_r0000gn/T/RackMultipart20170819-46445-2hop9q.png>, @original_filename="CSS-img.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images[]\"; filename=\"CSS-img.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f85acb99d60 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/7r/ypx2k4pd5jxgyy7kt6wzmv_r0000gn/T/RackMultipart20170819-46445-14xj5wc.png>, @original_filename="CSS.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images[]\"; filename=\"CSS.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">], 
"commit"=>"Add Banner", "id"=>"3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor inconsistency. Check the`banners_params` method in your `banners_controller.rb`

You are sending "images" but you are expecting "pictures". Change that to :

```
def banners_params
    params.require(:banner).permit(:name, images:[])
end
```

In `_form.html.erb`, and change

```
<%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
```

to

```
<%= f.file_field "images", type: :file, multiple: true %>
```

for `@banner.update(banners_params)` to work.

The above change will also need you to change your `create` method to use `banners_params[:images]` instead of `params[:images]`

Comment: Doesn't work. Everything works during the create method, but updating it doesn't work. So the params are correct, just something to do with the update